# Delete from Large Postgres tables in small batches based on timestamp using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I need to delete historic data (older than certain `timestamp`) from Postgres tables, similar to TTL in `NoSQL` database like MongoDB. Feature like `TTL` is not out of the box provided by SQL DB's like Postgres. While doing so I wish split the records into small batches so that I am not performing longer delete queries.

This clean up job will run in a Java based AWS lambda function which will be scheduled for a daily run. What is the best approach to achieve this using JDBC?

Comment: Why do you think you need to delete in batches? If you run this daily, I would assume you don't delete that many rows (millions at most) so I don't see a reason to not do this in a single DELETE statement. If you have a "constant TTL", then maybe partitioning might be a better option. Then you only drop the old partitions which is a matter of (milli)seconds

Comment: Too much data is accumulated in single day and multiple such tables are involved, always safer to delete in batches as the job will acquire the lock on the table.

Comment: A DELETE will not acquire a "lock on the table". It won't interfere with SELECT, UPDATE or INSERT statements (as long as they don't try to manipulate the rows to be deleted). And how much is "*too much data*"? billions of rows? Hundreds of millions? And if you are deleting from multiple tables, everything should be in a single transaction anyway to ensure consistency

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. `DELETE` does acquire a table lock, just not a strong one. See [Table Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I know, but nothing that would prevent regular DML statements.